When connecting Yandex maps in Android Studio, it gives an error that no implementation
I changed the implementation, updated the API key, searched for solutions on various forums, and added lines to the code. However, nothing helped, and the application crashes when clicking the button to switch to the activity with maps.

E  No implementation found for com.yandex.mapkit.MapKit com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory.getInstance() (tried Java_com_yandex_mapkit_MapKitFactory_getInstance and Java_com_yandex_mapkit_MapKitFactory_getInstance__) - is the library loaded, e.g., System.loadLibrary?  
2024-12-10 16:06:02.141 21995-21995 AndroidRuntime          com.example.rentalcar                D  Shutting down VM  
2024-12-10 16:06:02.143 21995-21995 AndroidRuntime          com.example.rentalcar                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
     Process: com.example.rentalcar, PID: 21995  
     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for com.yandex.mapkit.MapKit com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory.getInstance()
     (tried Java_com_yandex_mapkit_MapKitFactory_getInstance and Java_com_yandex_mapkit_MapKitFactory_getInstance__)
       - is the library loaded, e.g., System.loadLibrary?  
          at com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory.getInstance(Native Method)  
          at com.example.rentalcar.MapActivity.onStart(MapActivity.java:32)  
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1701)  
          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:9045)  
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4073)  
          at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:270)  
          at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:250)  
          at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:222)  
          at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeTransactionItems(TransactionExecutor.java:107)  
          at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:81)  
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2636)  
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)  
          at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)  
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)  
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8705)  
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)  
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)  


Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of your build files and the code you try to use.

Looks like a missing native library
